# How to add attribute to Title tag

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I'm using webforms ASP.NET, with masterpages.  I want to add a LANG attribute to the `<title>` tag.  ASP.NET automatically generates a title tag.  I've tried adding my own  tag with an ID and runat="server", like this:

```
<title id="titleBlock" runat="server"></title>
```

When doing this, I can set an attribute like the following without any errors.

```
titleBlock.Attributes.Add("lang", "it");
```

However, ASP.NET wipes out my `<title>` tag completely and puts its own in without my LANG attribute.  Is there any way to accomplish this?  Thanks very much.

Comment: Are you using master pages? Is the master page/content page overriding this?

Comment: @Oded, yes I'm using masterpages (first sentence of my question says so).  The content page is setting the Title via Page.Title = "...".  The code I show in my question (where I added my own title tag) is being done directly in the masterpage codebehind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because the **HtmlTitle** control doesn't provide a **RenderAttributes** implementation. You can't (easily) subclass the control in this case but there's another option. The power of **Control Adapters** isn't limited to WebControls - the concept also [extends](http://blogs.x2line.com/al/archive/2007/01/31/2814.aspx) to HtmlControls as well.

Drop the following in a *.browser file under the **App_Browsers** directory of your site:

```
<browsers>
  <browser refID="Default">
    <controlAdapters>
      <adapter 
        controlType="System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlTitle"
        adapterType="HtmlTitleAdapter" 
      />
    </controlAdapters>
  </browser>
</browsers>
```

Here's a prototype for the corresponding adapter:

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;

public class HtmlTitleAdapter : System.Web.UI.Adapters.ControlAdapter
{
    protected override void Render(System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        HtmlTitle title = Control as HtmlTitle;

        writer.WriteBeginTag("title");
        title.Attributes.Render(writer);
        writer.Write(">");

        if (title.Text != null)
            writer.Write(title.Text);

        writer.WriteEndTag("title");
    }
}
```

Note that the internal render implementation of HtmlTitle differs somewhat:

```
protected internal override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Title);
    if (this.HasControls() || base.HasRenderDelegate())
    {
        this.RenderChildren(writer);
    }
    else if (this._text != null)
    {
        writer.Write(this._text);
    }
    writer.RenderEndTag();
}
```

I'm not sure when a title would have child elements, so I don't think this an issue.

Hope this helps.

As an aside, it would be much easier to add this attribute on the client using jQuery.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("title").attr("lang", "it");
    });
</script>
```

Comment: It works -- wonderful solution, thank you.  I understand this would be easy to do with jQuery, but the main reason I'm doing this is for search engines so they recognize the language used in a few elements on the page (title tag, and a couple of DIVs).  Search engines aren't going to run JS, so need to output the LANG attribute directly from the server.  Thx again.